# Error: While creating new Site from a Site template

Tags: 2010, site-template

I am getting following error while creating new Site from a Site template.

[image]

Comment: I'd be interested to see the ULS Log for that Correlation ID as well. That might provide some more clues as well.

Comment: Thx. But have solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that for some reason the content type name isn't begin resolved, so SharePoint tries to create it with the name "$Resources:IWAssociatedField,RelatedDocumentContentType". This will then fail, since a content type name cannot contain character such as ":".

You need to identify the reason for the missing resource resolution. Was the content type provisioned by a feature no more available? Was the site template "migrated" from another server? Your first priority should be confirming if the above resource exists somewhere on the server, then checking if it contains the searched key.

Comment: It worked!. "$Resources:IWAssociatedField,RelatedDocumentContentType" was actually a third party app which had to be uninstalled to remove the error. In Site Settings > Site Content Types > above mentioned was listed which was removed after consulting the creator company. Thanks!